# Why doesn't the delete button works fine ? need help in python and flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask,session,render_template,request,session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
```

**Setting notes to an empty array:**

```
notes = []

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
 #this is the function for submit button
def index():

if request.method == "POST:
    note = request.form.get("note")


    notes.append(note)
```

**Note is getting the HTML value of note, and then notes is appending to note:**

```
return render_template("index.html",notes = notes)

@app.route("/",methods =["GET","POST"])
#this is the function for delete function
def delete():
 if request.method =="POST":
    number = request.form.get("number")
    notes.remove(notes[number])
 return render_template("index.html" , notes = notes)
```

I am creating a form which accepts or note down which I input as a text in the form section which has a function index.

The other function is for the delete button. It also has a form in HTML with only numbers can be input.

If I choose number 1, then it must delete the first item in the list but it's not happening here.

**HTML section is given below:**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h1>Notebook</h1>

  <form action="{{url_for('index')}}" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Enter the input">
  <button> Submit </button>

 </form>
 <form action = "{{url_for('delete')}}" method="POST">
 <input type="number" name="number">
 <button>Delete</button>
 </form>
 <ul> {%for note in notes%}
 <li>{{note}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>

</body>
</html>

}
```

Comment: Please make sure any code you include here _exactly_ communicates your question. We have no way of knowing if the mismatched quote in your second snippet (the source code highlighting makes it obvious) is the cause of your problem or just at typo here.

Comment: Can you describe the actual behaviour? Are you able to add multiple times to notes but you can never delete? Please write down a scenario. Also you are using a variable for persistence, you should not.

Comment: @Saksow Yes it updates the notes when i type something in the form and then submit via submit button. But when i press the delete button with or without a value it add "none" to the notes and updates the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit mixed up, as there are 2 app routes for index and both contain a post request. Try something like the following, I have no access to all your code so this is untested, please adjust where needed. I'm sure you get the idea:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
def index():
if request.method == "POST:
    if request.form.post['action'] == 'Append':
        note = request.form.get("note")
        notes.append(note)

    if request.form.post['action'] == 'Delete':
        number = request.form.get("number")
        notes.remove(notes[number])

 return render_template("index.html" , notes = notes)
```

in your html put the buttons in the right places something like this:

```
<input type ="submit" name="action" value="Append">     
<input type ="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
```